# Maximum number of subtree in a spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Is it possible to determine the theoretical maximum of number of subtree that can be extracted from a spanning tree?

**Some context** (I don't know whether this is useful): I build the spanning tree by traversing the control-flow graph (of a function in a computer program) in a depth-first search manner. So, I can safely assume that a node in the spanning tree can only have 1 parent and at the same time, can have multiple childern.

Comment: I don't understand completely. If a node in your tree can have multiple parents, is it then even a tree at all?

Comment: Oops sorry, I mixed the parent and children. Now, I have updated the context. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: How is this different from computing the number of subtrees of a rooted tree?